# Can we just get rid of "too broad" on meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, close-reasons

"Too broad" questions are pretty clearly okay on meta much of the time. Like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214966/183887). Nonetheless I voted to close it out of sheer moral sense of duty, because it does happen to fit the definition of "too broad" to the tee:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

This is wrong. These close votes are part of our voice for what questions are germane.

Now, there are a few takes on this:

- the community on meta is small enough that we can let culture and mores dictate exceptions, without bothering to codify or even articulate it. (This is my view of the current system.)
- Experienced users (the OP on example questions has 37k rep) can do what they want since they know better. Also true but terribly inconsistent with SE forums culture.

Anyway as usual, TPTB can figure out if this is worth the development effort to correct, or we can add it to the list of ways SO is kludged up for meta. But it's not great as is.

Comment: Surprised someone with 9.4K meta rep would use [the "F" word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92110#92110).

Comment: So you see a question that you think should stay open, and vote to close it?

Comment: @MartinSmith http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92113/183887 from your link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off:

> Nonetheless I voted to close it out of sheer moral sense of duty

Wait, you think the discussion is OK but you voted to close it anyway? That's... stupid. Don't do that. Close things that are problematic, not things that are fine but which a close description can be made to fit. Close descriptions are brief summaries of common problems, not carefully-drafted *laws that must be obeyed*.

Second, no, we're not doing per-site pruning of close reasons. Yeah, some of them don't apply on some sites. Some of them identify problems that *never occur* on some sites. So what? They're there if you ever need them.

Finally, there *are* overly-broad questions even for Meta, just as there are questions which are too "opinion-based" even for Meta. Just because we generally allow questions that are broader and more subject to opinionated answers here doesn't mean there's *no* limit - and if a question is causing problems, it's nice to have a ready reason that describes it.

Comment: +1 for *Close descriptions are brief summaries of common problems, not carefully-drafted laws that must be obeyed.* On the flipside, closure for reasons not on the list is also okay, hence the free-text 'Other...' close reason. The close reasons, at least if I'm understanding them right, are meant to save close-voters some boilerplate typing when expressing their reasons for closing stuff, not to enumerate the legitimate reasons for closure - but I think that not everybody shares that interpretation.